# deployed react app gives blank page on reloading in inner routes

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router, production

I have server the react app production build with a nginx server. All works fine except reloading in inner routes gives a blank page.

**Eg : "http://server.com/admin/anyroute"**

But there's is no issue in 1st level inner routes like "http://server.com/admin".

I have handled these catches in these nginx location blocks

```
location /api/static/ {
        proxy_pass http://dns-be/static/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://dns-be/api/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

# location /static/ {
#       proxy_pass http://dns-be/static/;
#       proxy_set_header Host $host;
#       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
# }


root /var/www/domain.com;

location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;

}
```

in package.json,

```
"homepage": ".",
```

I have tried using

```
"homepage": "/",
```

but it didn't even worked.

Is there any recommendation for this issue ?